# Moq error: "Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed"

Tags: c#, moq, botframework

I'm new to Moq and I'm struggling with this error. I'm not quite sure why I'm receiving the error that I am getting. I was following along with the test code found [here](https://gist.github.com/createdincode/5f753dff9403375f4e373cf06ab5aeb4).

**Error:**

> Moq.MockException: 
>   Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: c => c.PostAsync(Mock.Object, "You send abc which was 3 characters")

**Code**

**MyTests.cs**

```
[TestClass] 
public class MyTests
{
    private Mock<IChatHelper> _chat;
    private RootDialog _dialog;
    private Mock<IDialogContext> _context;

    public LUISDialogTests()
    {
        _chat = new Mock<IChatHelper>();
        _context = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
        _dialog = new RootDialog(_chat.Object);
    }

    //[SetUp]
    //public void SetUp()
    //{
    //    _chat = new Mock<IChatHelper>();
    //    _dialog = new RootDialog(_chat.Object);
    //    _context = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
    //}

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test_CustomerService_Message_LengthAsync()
    {
        var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

        message.Text = "abc";

        _chat.Setup(c => c.PostAsync(_context.Object, message.Text));

        await _dialog.MessageReceivedAsync(_context.Object, Awaitable.FromItem(message));

        _chat.Verify(c => c.PostAsync(_context.Object, "You send abc which was 3 characters"), Times.AtLeastOnce); // Fails here

    }
   }
```

**RootDialog.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
  private IChatHelper _chat;

public RootDialog(IChatHelper chat)
{
    _chat = chat;
}

public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var message = await result as Activity;

    int length = (message.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

    await _chat.PostAsync(context, $"You sent {message.Text} which was {length} characters");

    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

**ChatHelper.cs**

```
 public interface IChatHelper
{
    Task PostAsync(IDialogContext context, string message);
}

[Serializable]
public class ChatHelper : IChatHelper
{
    public async Task PostAsync(IDialogContext context, string message)
    {
        await context.PostAsync(message);
    }
}
```

**One thing to note:**

- The code I'm following suggests using [TestFixture] instead of [TestClass]. VS couldn't see the tests when Fixture was added so I swapped to test class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a one character typo in the message you are expecting. Your code under test does this:

```
await _chat.PostAsync(context, $"You sent {message.Text} which was {length} characters");
```

and you are verifying that this happened:

```
_chat.Verify(c => c.PostAsync(_context.Object, "You send abc which was 3 characters"), Times.AtLeastOnce); // Fails here
```

Can you spot the difference in the two strings? `sent` != `send`. Change one or other, and it'll probably start working.